# MySQL Replication not working properly on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx Server

Tags: mysql, replication, ubuntu

I have two Linux boxes. On the master following is the configuration file (my.cnf)

```
log-bin       = master-bin
log-bin-index = master-bin.index
binlog-do-db  = test_db
server-id     = 1
```

master status is as follows:

```
mysql> show master status;
+-------------------+----------+----------------+------------------+
| File              | Position | Binlog_Do_DB   | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+-------------------+----------+----------------+------------------+
| master-bin.000026 |      106 | test_db        |                  |
+-------------------+----------+----------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The configuration file on slave is:

```
server-id = 2
relay-log-index = slave-relay-bin.index
relay-log   = slave-relay-bin
replicate-do-db=test_db
```

The slave status is:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 207.216.74.213
                  Master_User: repl_user
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: master-bin.000027
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 276
               Relay_Log_File: slave-relay-bin.000141
                Relay_Log_Pos: 422
        Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000027
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: test_db
                   Last_Errno: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 276
              Relay_Log_Space: 723
              Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

*I've removed some empty entries from status above*

Slave does connect and is showing correct master log file, but I am not getting any data from master to slave.

The only thing I can found is that master has version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10-log or MySQL but slave has 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10.

Is the version or something other is creating problem?

Answer (score 2):

:D it was `binlog_do_db`. I removed it and now it is working fine.